# No accents in an utf-8 webservice

Tags: utf-8

I'm developing a webservice written in C and hosted by a RedHat 6.3 box. The box locale is fr_FR.UTF-8.
When I curl my webservice from the command line, I can read text content contaning accents on the command line.
However, when I check the WS output through the Chrome Developer tools and in the webpage output, the accents are replaced by a square containing an interrogation mark.
The content type of the webservice output is application/json; charset=utf-8.
The webpage charset is utf-8, browser is in autodetect.
What did I miss that unables me to properly display accents with utf-8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by checking the way the accented content was generated. Actually mine was generated by Postgresql, whose configuration parameter client_encoding was set to ascii, un changed client_encoding to 'UTF8', thsi solved my issue.